# Two text lines in `flalign` environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I want to achieve what the picture shows below. Basically, I want those two very long text lines to split into two lines shown below. My major problem is that if I keep the text in one line in `flalign`, then the entire right-side text will shift to the left. Here is my code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\newcommand \widebox[1]{\setlength\fboxsep{6pt}\boxed {\enspace#1\enspace}}
\newcommand \dpartial[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand \ddef[2]{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
\newcommand \spac{\\[0.6em]}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\title{\vspace{-5em} QM Formula List}
\author{David}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{flalign*}
   &i\hbar \dpartial{\Psi}{t} = -\frac{\hbar ^2}{2m}\dpartial{^2 \Psi}{x^2}+V\Psi &&\text{Shr\"odinger Equation}\spac
   &\widehat{p} = -i \hbar \dpartial{}{x}                                         &&\text{Momentim Operator} \spac
   &\widehat{H} = -\frac{\hbar ^2}{2m} \ddef{^2 \psi}{x^2} + V                    &&\text{Energy Operator} \spac
   &-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\ddef{^2 \psi}{x^2} + V \psi = E \psi                      &&\text{Time-independent Schr\"odinger Equation} \spac
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the item in a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\newcommand \widebox[1]{\setlength\fboxsep{6pt}\boxed {\enspace#1\enspace}}
\newcommand \dpartial[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand \ddef[2]{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
\newcommand \spac{\\[0.6em]}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\title{\vspace{-5em} QM Formula List}
\author{David}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{flalign*}
   &i\hbar \dpartial{\Psi}{t} = -\frac{\hbar ^2}{2m}\dpartial{^2 \Psi}{x^2}+V\Psi &&\text{Shr\"odinger Equation}\spac
   &\widehat{p} = -i \hbar \dpartial{}{x}                                         &&\text{Momentim Operator} \spac
   &\widehat{H} = -\frac{\hbar ^2}{2m} \ddef{^2 \psi}{x^2} + V                    &&\text{Energy Operator} \spac
   &-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\ddef{^2 \psi}{x^2} + V \psi = E \psi                      &&\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}Time-independent \\ Schr\"odinger Equation\end{tabular} \spac
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works! But somehow, I feel the format is weird, because it's not very common to put one environment into another, here `tabular` into `flalign`.

Comment: @Lawerance: Says who?! :) You can define `\newcommand \texttab[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}}` and then use `\texttab{... \\ ...}` if that is more appealing.

Comment: Ok, I think I need to look more into similar cases. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Use of `parbox[length]{content}` is another option.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\newcommand \widebox[1]{\setlength\fboxsep{6pt}\boxed {\enspace#1\enspace}}
\newcommand \dpartial[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand \ddef[2]{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
\newcommand \spac{\\[0.6em]}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\title{\vspace{-5em} QM Formula List}
\author{David}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{flalign*}
   &i\hbar \dpartial{\Psi}{t} = -\frac{\hbar ^2}{2m}\dpartial{^2 \Psi}{x^2}+V\Psi &&\text{Shr\"odinger Equation}\spac
   &\widehat{p} = -i \hbar \dpartial{}{x}                                         &&\text{Momentim Operator} \spac
   &\widehat{H} = -\frac{\hbar ^2}{2m} \ddef{^2 \psi}{x^2} + V                    &&\text{Energy Operator} \spac
   &-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\ddef{^2 \psi}{x^2} + V \psi = E \psi                      &&\parbox{4cm}{Time-independent Schr\"odinger Equation} \spac
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lawerance -- You are welcome.

Comment: I just found a minor problem. If we use `\parabox`, it is hard to keep the same space between characters in box as the one in the `\text`. For example, in `&&\parbox{5.3cm}{General Solution to the Separable Shr\"odinger Equation} \spac`, I need to keep adjusting the `width` until it becomes roughly the same as the one in `\text`. Do you have any better idea?

Comment: Hi, thanks for being patient for this late response. Indeed, that is a feature of the solution; A possible improvement is to determine the text length of ALL (called \abc) and use a macro, taking 1 argument, like \newcommand{\mytextwidth}[1]{\parbox[\widthof{\abc}]{#1} } which needs calc package.

Comment: Got it! i Think I will just do `newcommand`, because it is more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Your formulae are on left margin. To have them (more) centred, you should add a pair of `&&` in front of them. If you want them to be really centred, you can use the `alignat*` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}

\newcommand \widebox[1]{\setlength\fboxsep{6pt}\boxed {\enspace#1\enspace}}
\newcommand \dpartial[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand \ddef[2]{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
\newcommand \spac{\\[0.6em]}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\title{\vspace{-5em} QM Formula List}
\author{David}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{flalign*}
  &  &   &i\hbar \dpartial{\Psi}{t} = -\frac{\hbar ^2}{2m}\dpartial{^2 \Psi}{x^2}+V\Psi &&\text{Shrödinger Equation}\spac
  &  &   &\widehat{p} = -i \hbar \dpartial{}{x}                                         && \text{Momentum Operator}\spac
  &  &   &\widehat{H} = -\frac{\hbar ^2}{2m} \ddef{^2 \psi}{x^2} + V    &&\text{Energy Operator} \spac
   &  &  &-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\ddef{^2 \psi}{x^2} + V \psi = E \psi      & &\Centerstack[l]{Time-independent\\ Schrödinger Equation} \spac
\end{flalign*}
\vskip2ex
\begin{alignat*}{2}
   &i\hbar \dpartial{\Psi}{t} = -\frac{\hbar ^2}{2m}\dpartial{^2 \Psi}{x^2}+V\Psi &&\text{\rlap{\hspace{4em}Shrödinger Equation}}\spac
   &\widehat{p} = -i \hbar \dpartial{}{x}                                         & &\text{\rlap{\hspace{4em}Momentum Operator}}\spac
   &\widehat{H} = -\frac{\hbar ^2}{2m} \ddef{^2 \psi}{x^2} + V    &&\text{\rlap{\hspace{4em}Energy Operator}} \spac
   &-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\ddef{^2 \psi}{x^2} + V \psi = E \psi      &&\rlap{\hspace{4em}\Centerstack[l]{Time-independent\\ Schrödinger Equation}} \spac
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks still! But I want the equations to be displayed on the left and text the left, because there will be hundreds of them.